# Montgomery Reduction with Even Modulus

Tags: montgomery-multiplication

Montgomery Reduction requires that $gcd(R,N) = 1$, where N is the original modulus and R is the selected modulus which is like $2^k,k\in\mathbb{N}$, because the computer adopts binary coding.
When N is odd, R and N must be prime, but when N is even, we cannot find the R in form $2^k,k\in\mathbb{N}$.

The paper [“Montgomery Reduction with Even Modulus”](https://cetinkayakoc.net/docs/j34.pdf) proposes a solution, but the citation is very low. Why? Is there a better solution? Or because in engineering practice N is always odd?

Comment: citation is low != it is not working. `When N is odd, R and N must be prime` This is over the GCD assumption. They may have an implementation, did you contact them? besides, you can link the paper on your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have reedited the question. Also, I haven't read the article, but because of the low citations, I wonder if this method is not used much. I'll read it first